# Are namespaces created in memory?

Tags: python, memory, namespaces

I am a complete novice so this may be a silly question. Are namespaces in `Python` created in memory? And if they are, in which part of the memory they are created?

Comment: Everything that isn't saved to files is in memory. What do you mean by "which part of memory"?

Comment: @Barmar Like heap, stack, etc

Comment: It's probably in the heap, since it's not local to a specific function. But it depends entirely on the Python implementation.