# What is meant by assignment is a statement in Python?

Tags: python, assignment-operator

In the official Python documentation, the assignment `=` is referred to as a statement or an expression. I really don't get it what it means by *assignment is a statement*. How is assignment a statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement is code that tells the computer to do something. A statement has to be written by itself on a line. Examples are assignments, `def` to define functions, and `while` to start a loop.

An expression is code that calculates a value, and can be used as part of another statement or expression. Examples are arithmetic calculations, function calls, literal values, and comprehensions.

Since assignments are not expressions, you can't use them as part of another statement. For instance, you can't write:

```
if i = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    # do something
```

You have to do this in two steps:

```
i = int(input("Enter a number:"))
if i:
    # do something
```

Python 3.8 added a new operator `:=`. This is the operator for an *assignment expression*, described in detail in [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), which can be used as above:

```
if i := int(input("Enter a number:")):
    # do something
```

Comment: The assignment is not an operator in Python, right?

Comment: That's correct. It's part of the syntax of an assigment statement.

Comment: Hey, I liked your way of answering the question. Please answer this one too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61952036/13595466

Comment: @anarchy No, not at all. I am using this to ameliorate my perspicaciousness by people who are ready to purvey chasmic insight.

Comment: Please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62073294/13595466. The documentation has used the term *assignment operators*.

Comment: The `:=` assignment operator is part of an assignment expression, just as the `+` operator is part of an addition expression.

Comment: No, it has called ```=``` an assignment operator.